How to make Azure Batch Transcription call a URL or Function App on completion using .NET?
I’m working on a project where I need to use Azure Cognitive Services to perform batch transcriptions on audio files. My goal is to upload an audio file, trigger the batch transcription, and then have Azure notify a URL or an Azure Function App once the transcription is complete. There doesn't seem to be an option in the call to batch transcription. How can I do this?
Example call to batch transcription in .NET:
string endpoint = $"https://{speechServiceRegion}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.1/transcriptions";
var requestBody = new
{
    contentUrls = new[] { blobSasUri },
    properties = new
    {
        diarizationEnabled = false,
        wordLevelTimestampsEnabled = false
    },
    locale = "en-GB",
    displayName = "Batch transcription using Azure Function",
};

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", speechServiceKey);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));


yes, i've added some.

refer to this example to use Batch Transcription

The Speech to Text APIs include a WebHook Creation API that you will have to setup once to direct events to a service of your choice.
There will intially be a validation request that you need to respond with a 200 response for the WebHook to successfully registered.
